# Is this good practice for react functional components?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, functional-programming, garbage-collection, components

Recently I've been writing more and more of my react components in a functional style, since most of them don't need the lifecycle functions or state. Inside my components (which are, again, just functions) I define helper functions - onClick functions and all that jazz. But now I'm thinking if this is good practice? Since the function is called for each render, does it recreate all the internal functions? I'm curious about memory loss and whether I'm doing this wrong.... An example of a component:

```
import React from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

import ProductSearch from '../Plan/components/ProductSearch';

const BlockedProducts = (props) => {
  const onSelectProduct = (product_key) => {
    console.log(product_key);
  };

  return (
    <ProductSearch onSelectProduct={ onSelectProduct } />
  );
};

export default connect()(BlockedProducts);
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes, there will definitely be some performance hit by virtue of the fact that you're declaring a function every single time you render `BlockedProducts`. How efficiently that gets cleaned up from garbage collection I don't know, but it seems best not to press your luck.

Functional components in React are really meant to be completely stateless and not "do" anything except be presentational. The ideal functional component just returns some JSX/HTML to render, no bells and whistles. In my opinion, a functional component should ONLY have a return, and as soon as you start adding interior functions it should be upgraded to a full fledged React class.

Comment: There's nothing wrong with a functional component that utilizes other functions or attaches stateless event handlers to its children elements/components. Only when you need state or lifecycle hooks should you upgrade to a stateful Component.

Answer (score 0):

You could move the `onSelectProduct` declaration from `BlockedProducts` scope by putting it above component. It will make a closure to component's scope, because `BlockedProducts` declaration will be in the same scope with `onSelectProduct`.

I don't think that it will cause some perf issues. I do agree with @jered - a stateless components should be as simple as possible, so try to don't make any business logic there.

Answer (score 0):

I have came to the same question recently. https://github.com/yannickcr/eslint-plugin-react/issues/357 Daniel discusses that this approach will increase GC workload, so he uses class components instead.

I would argue that first of all class components are for handling lifecycle and state and they also have impact to performance by creating backing bean, that suppose to deal with lifecycles and state.

Therefore I would use functional class instead and create class components when real performance issues will arise

Btw, 10 months have passed, I am curious which approach you have finally sticked with?